# Create various beans dynamically

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

for a current project I would like to have the following capability:

"For any interface extending interface X, create a bean via this static factory method, using another (autowired) bean."

Finding all interfaces extending X is no problem, reflections does that quite well. But I haven't yet found any way to inject myself into the Spring lifecycle so that Springs knows that these beans can exist.

Currently, I'm trying to do it with a simple bean...

```
@Component
public class DynamicBeanFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Service myService;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    protected List<Class<? extends X>> findAllSubclasses() { ... }

    @PostConstruct
    public void createOneBeanPerClass() { 
      ... create beans from findAllSubclasses(), using myService
      beanFactory.registerSingleton(name, bean);
    }
}
```

Obviously this leads to problem, since, for example...

```
@Autowired
private YextendingX dependency;
```

...doesn't work all the time, since Spring has no way of knowing that `YextendingX` will only be available after the `DynamicBeanFactory` has been created, which leads to the need of a `@DependsOn("dynamicBeanFactory")`, just to be sure.

So, is there a better way to inject a Bean(definition) into the lifecycle, so that some factory class is used to create a number of bean(definitions), with the ability to use `@Autowired` there.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around for a while, the following solutions seems to do the trick...

```
@Component
public class DynamicBeanRegistryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {

        List<Class<? extends X> classes = findAllSubclasses(); // implemented via Reflections

        for (Class<? extends X> clz : classes) {

             RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(clz);
             beanDefinition.setTargetType(clz);
             beanDefinition.setFactoryBeanName("myFactoryBean");
             beanDefinition.setFactoryMethodName("myFactoryMethod");

             ConstructorArgumentValues properties = new ConstructorArgumentValues();
             properties.addGenericArgumentValue("someString");
             properties.addGenericArgumentValue(clz);            
             beanDefinition.setConstructorArgumentValues(properties);

             beanDefinition.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
             beanDefinition.setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON);
             registry.registerBeanDefinition(entry.getKey(), beanDefinition );
        }   

    }
etc.
```

This way, all the beans seem to found and added as bean definitions, so their creation order can be determined correctly. For creating them, the method `myFactoryMethod` is called on the bean `myFactoryBean`, using the two parameters `"someString"` and the `class` `clz` of the desired bean.